# How to install Vivaldi on Mac?

Tags: installation, macos-catalina, vivaldi

I have downloaded the Vivaldi installer for Mac "Vivaldi.2.11.1811.38.dmg" from the Vivaldi website. Then I doubleclicked the installer file in `Finder` and agreed to the software agreement. Then this window without text and without buttons was displayed:

[image]

It is not clear from this SIGN LANGUAGE dialog what I should do now, as I don't speak the sign language. I have tried to double-click the Applications icon, but it shows only a list of the installed applications.

So how must I proceed now to install Vivaldi on Mac?

Comment: This type of installation is very common on a mac actually. Just drag what is on the left ontop of the link on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drag the Vivaldi.app icon from the left and drop to the Applications folder on the right.

That’s it.

Go to Applications on your Mac and it’s there!

Comment: I am new to Mac. Does the Mac not use human-readable text in its dialogs? Or are Mac users not able to read human text?

Comment: Actually, it depends on the developer of the application. There are some developers mentioned in the drag & drop window to give instructions to users.

Comment: How many languages would you like your human readable text in? Most Mac Apps 'install' this way, because actually no 'installation' is usually required. Once you've seen it once, you don't need telling ever again, so it's just duplicated effort.